# Binding to a quantity and a measurement unit

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm new to WPF development and I'm looking for advice regarding a recurrent databinding pattern within my application.

In the database I'm working with, there's quite an heavy usage of measurement units and associated values.

For the sake of demonstration, here's some stripped-down table structures that might give some clues on what I have to work with:

### SampleTable

- (...)
- Quantity
- MeasurementUnitId
- (...)

### SampleTable2

- (...)
- Speed
- DistanceMeasurementUnitId
- TimeMeasurementUnitId
- (...)

### SampleTable3

- (...)
- Distance
- MeasurementUnitId
- (...)

### SampleTableN (etc...)

- (...)
- Weight
- WeightMeasurementUnitId
- Volume
- VolumeMeasurementUnitId
- (...)

### MeasurementUnits

- Id
- MeasurementUnitTypeId
- ShortName
- ConversionFactor
- (...)

### MeasurementUnitTypes

- Id
- ShortName
- (...)

I hope the names speaks for themselves. :)

The way the system works, the stored values must all be in a default system unit. A user writing 10 meters in the UI won't make the value stored as 10, it will be converted to a system value before. For example, with a distance value, if the distance unit type's default measurement unit is centimeters, then the stored value will actually be 1 000, because 1 000 cm = 10 meters.

The measurement unit that was used by the user is still stored in the database, however. This is to ensure that the next time he opens up the record in the UI again, he actually sees 10 meters, not 1 000 cm. A converstion must of course be performed there too.

There is one system unit per unit measurement type. It's the one that has the ConversionFactor set to 1. Other measurement units has a ConversionFactor that relates to that. Taking back the distance exampler higher above:

- CM: 1
- M: 100
- KM: 100 000
- (etc.)

In the UI, I'd like to use a textbox to write the number and a combobox loaded with measurement units filtered on the unit type, according to the context. When the user loads the data, it must appear as it was entered (converted according to the associated measurement unit). When he types in the value, the binding mechanism must write the correct, converted value back in the entity class, according to the currently selected measurement unit's ConversionFactor.

When he chooses the measurement unit, depending on his personnal settings, two things may happen:

- The displayed number changes and the stored number remains the same
- The displayed number remains the same and the stored number is converted

Now my question is... how much of this functionnality I can encapsulate for easy reusing? And what's the best way of doing this?

Please be aware that I might need these fields to be displayed separately sometimes. In a grid for example, I want a column for both the numeric part and the unit part. This is for allowing filtering and sorting on the unit alone.

I don't mind having to recreate the unit list/combo/whatever control everytime. I'm mainly interested in reusing the unit conversion part.

Thanks for reading this far (whew!) and for any ideas you can think of. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to WPF, the first thing you should do is to study the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern.

If you structure your application this way, you can create a common ViewModel type to be used for all of your unit list/combo/whatever controls, which encapsulates the logic of doing the unit conversions.

Comment: I did study MVVM, though I probably have a lot more to learn. My question was more about WPF databinding specifics. Or did I get something wrong and MVVM's really supposed to fill the hole here?

Comment: The VM is where you handle all the logic (e.g. unit conversions, choosing the list of units, etc), and it basically just presents the relevant data to the view to be databound. So the text part would just be bound to a numeric property (probably using a converter to go from string to numeric), the specified unit would be bound to another property, and the list of available units (i.e. the ItemsSource of the combo) would be bound to a third property.

Comment: Okay but sometimes I also have to display the system value as well. This is common for stocking measurement units, people wants to see both a number of boxes and a number of products. I want any changes to any of these fields to make the other one react, and I need this pattern to be repeated often for many ModelView objects.

Comment: Then you can expose the system value as another property. You can make them cause changes to the other properties by including the logic in your ViewModel and then raising property changed events for any modified properties.

Comment: And you can make the pattern repeatable by having this be a base class for view models to derive from.

Comment: Well this is where it gets flaky. I can't just have a base class that has Quantity and MeasurementUnitId properties. As you can see in the data model up above, I have multiple different scenarios where conversion needs to be achieved. Plus, a base class would be efficient for only one recurring pattern. If I ever have to support a new one (currency, culture-sensitive display/input text according to current culture, etc...), I'll end up with some God base object that will be anything but friendly or efficient.

Comment: Before writing down this question I started up creating a special class that would be using inner objects as "extensions" for some fields. Using reflection I could trump the databinding mechanism into believing "Distance_Value" and "Distance_MeasurementUnitId" properties exists, while internally there really is only a Distance property typed as MeasurementUnitValued, which has the Value and MeasurementUnitId properties. With some attribute mapping I could then map the bound object's "real" properties to it's extension's. However, so far it represents quite a lot of work to make it right.

Comment: This is why I'm asking if there could be a better, easier solution. :)

Comment: I should mention that this "special" class was meant to be used as a base class afterwards. It would also need to be implementing IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo, well pretty much everything that makes WPF databinding magically works. :) The "extension" types would also be derived from a base extension class that holds the basic mapping mechanisms. This way, each "pattern" could be isolated in it's very own extension and lives as sibling properties within the "special class"-derived object.